# What are possible causes of CorruptVolumeException: LONG_RECORD chain in Sonar?

Tags: sonar-runner

When we run sonar-runner on a C++ code base we get this error:

```
com.persistit.exception.CorruptVolumeException: LONG_RECORD chain starting at 19245
```

One of the C++ header files is > 100,000 lines long (we didn't write it!).  What might Sonar be doing when this error occurs?  We're using MySQL; what does Sonar use persistit for?

What are the practical limits of Sonar?  Is it solely a function of available memory or are there other constraints?