# com.persistit.exception.CorruptVolumeException: LONG_RECORD chain starting at xxxxx is too long

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I'm performing sonar analysis and I get this below error:

```
Caused by: com.persistit.exception.CorruptVolumeException: LONG_RECORD chain starting at 415447 is too long
        at com.persistit.LongRecordHelper.corrupt(LongRecordHelper.java:240)
        at com.persistit.LongRecordHelper.fetchLongRecord(LongRecordHelper.java:118)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.fetchFixupForLongRecords(Exchange.java:3178)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.fetchFromValueInternal(Exchange.java:3113)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.fetchFromBufferInternal(Exchange.java:3081)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.traverse(Exchange.java:2247)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.traverse(Exchange.java:2063)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.traverse(Exchange.java:2523)
        at com.persistit.Exchange.hasNext(Exchange.java:2646)
        at org.sonar.batch.index.Cache$EntryIterator.hasNext(Cache.java:461)
```

Can someone please help me how to fix this? Once after this fix, my work is almost done.
Just stuck, please help me.

Regards
Eajaz

Comment: Someone had a similar question, it seems - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492682/what-are-possible-causes-of-corruptvolumeexception-long-record-chain-in-sonar

Answer (score 1):

It means SonarQube is trying to cache a very big value that is exceeding capacity of our caching library. You don't provide a lot of information (like SQ version or full stack trace) but most of the time this is caused by a file having tons of duplication (like a SQL DDL).

A ticket was created https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6000 and in the meantime you can exclude the offending file from duplication detection using sonar.cpd.exclusions

Comment: There's a previous question asked 24 days ago, maybe this answer should go there as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492682/what-are-possible-causes-of-corruptvolumeexception-long-record-chain-in-sonar

Comment: Thanks @Julien HENRY. Can you suggest some options to fix this issue?